# Can an Investigator move directly to the balcony without using the stairs in the Foyer?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

The rules say that it costs 1 movement point to move into a different area of the same tile.

[image: Foyer]

In the case of the Foyer it doesn't seem logical to move from the floor (1) directly to the balcony (2) without going through the central hallway/stair entrance area first.

Have I missed a rule to cover this special case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's no special case. The division between those areas is marked with a white border. The movement cost to cross a white border is 1.

I believe the FAQ addresses this issue specifically and says that it represents characters climbing over the banisters.

**EDIT**: I realized that if you read just the title of your question, it seems like I'm saying the opposite of what I really am. So:

**YES** - you can move directly to the balcony. **NO** - there is no special case, you haven't missed anything!